# Hide Xcode dsymutil warning about missing architecture info

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have an iOS app that is to be linked with several 3rd party prebuilt static libraries. Those static libraries have had their debug info stripped and apparently lost their architecture information as well. When building the app (simulator in this case) I receive lots of warnings like this :

```
/Developer/usr/bin/dsymutil 
warning: (i386) 'libtest.a(test.o)' doesn't contain architecture information for i386.
```

Is there any way to tell dsymutil to shut up about this? The app compiles and runs just fine but all those warnings are quite ugly and I would like to get rid of them. Any suggestions ?

Comment: can you provide maybe the list of 3rd party library that you are using. My understanding is that if the 3rd party library doesnt support simulator you may get the above error.

Comment: Try to set 'Build Active Architecture Only' = YES/NO. Also check 'Architectures' and 'Valid architectures' on 3rd party project settings.

Comment: may be you not set user header search path  and other linker flag in projects build setting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change the architectures in the project to only include armv7, and not the default.

Comment: You don't want to do this any more.https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10202014a

Answer (score 6):

I too was facing the same issue. After searching a lot what I found is

Changing **Build Settings** -> **Debug Information Format** value from *"DWARF with dSYM File"*  to **DWARF** fixes the problem and hides the warnings.

Comment: That doesn't really fix the problem; it just masks it.  And it creates an even bigger problem: when your app crashes in the field, the crash logs you get from Apple, Crashlytics, etc. will no longer be useful.  They'll only tell you what function or method your app crashed in, with no line numbers.

Comment: Filed rdar://23337914 asking for a way to decrease the verbosity of dsymutil warnings to one message per stripped framework or archive.